# Convergence of $a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

given $\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n + b_n) = c ∈ R $.

And given  $\lim_{n\to \infty} (b_n) = \infty$.

How can I check if $a_n$ is converges? (and if it converges, it converges to finite number or to infinity?)

Comment: Hint: show that $\;\{a_n\}\;$ cannot converge to a finite number.

Answer (score 5):

Let $c_n=a_n+b_n$. Then $a_n =c_n -b_n $. This gives $a_n \to - \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this by contradiction too.

Assume $a(n)$ is convergent and say converges to $p$.

So,$lim_{n\to\infty}(a(n)+b(n))=p+\infty=\infty$,which is contradiction.

So,$a(n)$ must diverge.It can either diverge to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

But if $a(n)\to+\infty$,then again $lim_{n\to\infty}(a(n)+b(n))=+\infty$,which is not true.

Hence,$a(n)$ must diverge to $\color{red}{-\infty}$.